# How to use Objective C to send device token for push notifications and other user settings to sql table on server

Tags: mysql, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Ideally, I would like to send an HTTP Request using POST to the Push Notification Server that contains the device token as well as some user-defined settings. From there I can set up a php script on the server to deal with the incoming data and input it into an sql table. If this is the only way to do it, how would I go about initiating and HTTP Request from Objective C?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You'll first need to convert the device token to a hex string with a function like this:

```
- (NSString*)stringWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
  const char* data = [deviceToken bytes];
  NSMutableString* token = [NSMutableString string];

  for (int i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {
    [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
  }

  return [[token copy] autorelease];
}
```

Then you'll need to make a request to your server:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/script.php?token=%@", DEVICE_TOKEN]];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate: self];
```

Answer (score 10):

another way:

```
NSString * tokenAsString = [[[deviceToken description] 
stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] 
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```