# Can't urlencode deviceToken (Swift)

Tags: swift, ios8, nsdata, nsurl

I would like to send the deviceToken using NSURL session to my server, but it crashes every time. I've tried to find a way to convert the DataObject (the deviceToken) into NSString but did not succeed so far.

Error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Any help s greatly appreciated. Here's my code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken   deviceToken: NSData!) {
    let urlPath = "http://example.com/deviceToken=\(deviceToken)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?

    })

    task.resume()  
}
```

Comment: `"[http://example.com]&deviceToken=\(deviceToken)"` should be `"http://example.com&deviceToken=\(deviceToken)"`, without the square brackets. Where did you get that from?

Comment: Actually it probably should be `"http://example.com?deviceToken=\(deviceToken)"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you pinpoint what variable is being unwrapped and returning nil? I can't see anything that would cause that, except the URL, so your error might be an invalid URL. Remember NSURL validates the string given according to a strict syntax ([RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)). Try this URL (without the deviceToken) and see if that makes any difference:

```
let urlPath = "http://example.com/?deviceToken"
```

On a sidenote, the device token needs to be URL encoded, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979960/267892). Your whole method would then be as follows:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for var i = 0; i < deviceToken.length; i++ {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }
    let urlPath = "http://example.com/?deviceToken=\(tokenString)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?

    })

    task.resume() 

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I was trying to unwrap deviceToken, so your solution works fine.

Comment: Very minor comment - ```format: "%02hhx"``` is enough. No precision needed as every byte of ```device token``` is integer. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

Comment: This is deprecated in Xcode 7.3, please update your answer