# Push Notifications Cannot get Device Token

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'am trying to get the device token so I can send a notification to it but i keep getting the error "enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later."

The device is registered as I can turn the notifications off and on in the notification settings on the phone.  This is the code i'm using to try and retrieve the token:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
NSLog(@"This is device token%@", deviceToken);
}
```

im registering the device with this code:

```
if ([application   respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    NSLog(@"ios 8+: %@");
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    NSLog(@"< ios 8+: %@");
}
```

Ideally i'd like to retrieve the device tokens and send them to a mysql database, have no clue how to do this as i'm a web developer and not too familiar with Objective C

Comment: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not an error.
It is a valid callback once you register for push notifications
deviceToken as nsdata passed with it contains the device token you can extract and then most likely pass to your backend

Comment: My Bad the error is "enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later."

Comment: how are you registering for remote notifications?

Comment: just added it to the question.

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091875/how-to-update-code-using-enabledremotenotificationtypes-because-it-is-not-suppo

Comment: the problem is that the function 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken' wont fire

Comment: Weird, should fire, but also Please check in project settings whether the push notifications are enabled and whether you have generated push certificates for development/deployment at Apple developer website.

Comment: Also you won't get push notifications on simulator

Comment: im using my iphone 6 Plus, and if i go into notification setting its set to "allow Notifications"  even on the nslog is says im registered, but its saying that the function "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" is not supported in ios 8 or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you should register for remote notifications:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:types];
}
```

Also if you need to send it to your backend, you first take a look here and extract a string token in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`: [Iphone device token - NSData or NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587407/iphone-device-token-nsdata-or-nsstring)

Then use AFNetworking or NSURLSession to send it to your backend API.
Take a look here for example: [Send POST request using NSURLSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099448/send-post-request-using-nsurlsession)

Comment: Okay so deleted the app from the phone, added the new code then run it again through xcode. It prompt me to recieve notifications which i did but in the log it still wont give me my device token. "enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later."

Comment: you need to extract a token from NSData argument of didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587407/iphone-device-token-nsdata-or-nsstring

Then use this token and call your backend API in http post request (likely application/x-www-form-urlencoded format)

Comment: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken won't fire

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091875/how-to-update-code-using-enabledremotenotificationtypes-because-it-is-not-suppo

Comment: Yes that code works great, i can register! but I cannot retrieve the device token to the on NSlog to see it.

Comment: One way in one liner is to:  NSString *token = [[[[deviceToken description]
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

Comment: the problem is that the function 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken' wont fire.

Comment: found the issue, two cordova push notification plugins where installed for some reason. removed them and worked :)

Comment: Didn't know you are using Cordova) remember to specify in the question next time and also take a look what you can do with  Angular 2

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
 {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSString *myDeviceToken = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    myDeviceToken = [myDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"Device Token: %@", myDeviceToken);
}
```

Use above code to get Device Token, & to get Remote notification make sure your Background mode is ON for Remote notification

Comment: Add elaboration to your answer.

Comment: Use above code to get Device Token, & to get Remote notification make sure your Background mode is ON for Remote notification

Comment: Add that to your answer using the "Edit" button. I already did that for you, waiting for review.